# How to combine two PDO statements in one MySQL query?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

From what I know now about PDO statements and my own experiences on localhost and Google - there are some difficulties with using multiple PDO statements in one query. For instance this situation:

```
$stmt = $db_people->prepare("SELECT * FROM people WHERE online=1");
$stmt->execute();
$results_people = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

On this query I can do simple PDO statement like fetch (in example). But when I want to use PDO statement like this:

```
$rows = $stmt->rowCount();
```

It is not possible and the statement will not return the right number of rows. When I do it in the other way around and filling one of the column name - rowCount works correctly like this:

```
$stmt = $db_people->prepare("SELECT name FROM people WHERE online=1");
$stmt->execute();
$rows = $stmt->rowCount();
```

And adding fetch after that like this:

```
$results_people = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Will not work corectly in this example. My question is - How to combine two different PDO statements in one single query? Thank you.

Comment: First, you should try to avoid `SELECT *`, instead using the column names for which you need. If I read your question correctly, that should "fix" your problem too.

Comment: How does `SELECT *` produce a different `rowCount()` than `SELECT name`? I've never heard this before.

Comment: `Select *` will always return 1 `Select name` will return the right number of columns i.e. 100 in `rowCount()` function. That is the point of my question.

Comment: I think what you're looking for is `SELECT COUNT(*) as numberOfRows`. From the [rowCount](http://si.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php) manual "If the last SQL statement executed by the associated PDOStatement was a SELECT statement, some databases may return the number of rows returned by that statement. However, this behaviour is not guaranteed for all databases and should not be relied on for portable applications."

Comment: OK I will try that and report back.

Comment: Not work ... `COUNT(*)` is not reliable either ... Imagine two people in the table and `select * from myTable` will return 2 rows. `select count(*)` will return 1 result. `select count(*), user, id from myTable` will return one result ... So now what :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer probably depends on which operations you're trying to combine. For instance, if you're trying to combine `PDOStatement::rowCount()` with a `SELECT` SQL operation, then it's probably worthwhile to take notice of the warnings in the [`PDOStatement::rowCount()` description](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php) which says that `rowCount()` is not 100% reliable for SELECT statements in all databases.

If the problem you're trying to solve is specifically limited to counting the result rows of a SELECT, then another approach would be to use [`PDOStatement::fetchAll()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) and count the rows in the returned array.

Comment: I am trying to combine `SELECT * FROM people WHERE something=something AND something=something ...` fetchAll in this case will return in variable `$results_people["name"]` empty column even when there are like 50 of them and I have it in `while()`

Comment: That's not how the result array from `fetchAll()` is structured. The array is indexed by row, not column. For example, try `$results_people[0]["name"]`.